# Supported microphone sample rate on iOS

Tags: ios, microphone, sample-rate

I am trying to look up what sample rate is supported on all Android and iOS devices when recording audio via the microphone.

On Android the documentation clearly states that 44,1 kHz is currently the only value to be guaranteed to work on all devices ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord)).

However, I can not find any information about iOS. I can not find any concrete value which would be working on all devices. As far as I understand it newer iPhones currently use 48 kHz by default. I can resample the audio as suggested in this Stack Overflow question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927822/how-can-get-audio-with-sample-rate-of-44100-from-iphone-11-or-iphone-11-pro-max).

Is there any value that is guaranteed to be supported on all iOS devices?